# Why we need Shutdown port and Startup Port in Application/Service?

Tags: tomcat, service

I wonder about why we need one shutdown port and one startup port in Application/Service? For example, Tomcat has startup port 8080 and shutdown port 8085. Sorry if my question is so naive.

Answer (score 1):

There is no startup port, but (at least) one Connector binding on a port. All servers need to listen on a port for obvious reasons.

The shutdown port is not mandatory but you want to stop your process one day. Either you need to send a shutdown command to stop "cleanly", or you will stop roughly. When using the shutdown port, which is recommended, Tomcat will call the destroy() methods and then stop. You probably need further reading on what's a server, particularly in J2EE.

Comment: Thanks Eugènee for your information. About the startup port, it is my specific service need this port. So we can define port is "the bridge" for the connection between server and application/service?

Comment: The connector port is the port that your clients can connect to. Example : http://mysite:8080/ . Maybe you need to learn with some tutorials, this site is more dedicated to programming questions.